# Перестал парсится google. Что делать?

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Использую такой код.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;


public class parser1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
        String url=("https://www.google.ru/search?q=layta.ru");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Google Chrome (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                .timeout(10*10000).get();

        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            String temp = link.attr("href");
            if(temp.startsWith("/url?q=")){
                System.out.println(temp);
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

кажется что раньше работал хорошо, с временными ошибками, скорее всего связанными с самим качеством связи.

А сейчас все печально.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:571)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at parser1.main(parser1.java:18)
```

Comment: забанили в гугле?

Comment: Такое возможно? запрос через адресную строку спокойно проходит.

Comment: да. Ваш браузер использует другой юзер агент. И скорее всего он ходит на другой урл. wireshark  в руки и смотреть.

Comment: Я так полагаю, это не так просто. Есть способ проще? Может можно поменять юзер агента в гугле. Я меняю, но сохранить изменения не получается. И после смены, по идее, он либо так же перестанет работать как и код или наоборот позволит коду конектится?

Comment: думаю, хром скорее всего продолжит работать, Ваш код - нет.